# Unity Shadow shows on my Android device but NOT my Windows Mobile device

Tags: unity, windows, shadows

Unity version: 2017.1.1f1

**Problem:**

I'm using Directional Light. Shadow is not showing in my Windows Mobile device (Lumia 640 XL), but works fine when I run the **exact same UWP project as PC (Local Machine)** as well as Android.


**Attempted solutions:**

1) Quality Setting: I even removed the rest of levels and left only 1 level of quality.

2) Both soft and hard shadows, 10 Shadow distance, Stable Fit of shadow projection, very high resolution, low resolution, No Cascade.

3) Tried *realtime* and *mixed* light mode.


any idea? Thanks in advance for read my question.


**Screenshots:**

*Windows 10 Mobile (Lumia 640 XL)*

[image]


*Android (Redmi Note 3)*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. So the only conclusion I can make here is Lumia 640 XL cannot support anymore advanced 'fancy' stuff compared to other normal devices. Thats all I can assume. Thanks.

**Why I say so:**

I even changed to a very bright, obvious, closed to floor point light so that we *should* be able to notice that point light very clearly right in front my character and bright spot of light shine on floors. However, all of these simple effects cannot be seen on my Lumia 640 XL device.

Therefore, I have to give up on that. I'm sad about it but it's the truth.